# Request Review Subject not auto populating TFS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-code-review

I have added a Work item and tried Request Review in TFS. It was auto populating the subject and works great. But when I clicked Request Review without adding a Work item going back and adding work item trying to Request Review will not auto populate the subject for review. Why this happen? .Anybody having a solution for this. I restart Visual studio for getting subject.

Comment: Can you share the detailed steps? I cannot reproduce the issue via this step: Click Request Review with and without work Item added -> Click Cancel -> Add work item -> Click Request Review.

Comment: Subject is auto populated for you in that request review ?

Comment: Yes with format "Code Review for xxx".

Comment: Step Click Request Review with and without work Item added -> Click BackButton -> Add work item -> Click Request Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject is generated automatically when create a new request review. But when you click "Back" button, the Request Review isn't cancelled, it just go back to previous screen to allow you update the request review. So when you click "Request Review" again, the subject is not changed(Keep empty in your scenario). So you just need to click "Cancel" button to cancel the request review and then add the work item and click "Request Review" again, the new subject will be generated.